# Automatic Failover for Basic Availability Group

Tags: high-availability, failover, sql-server-2019, hadr, basic-availability-groups

This will be my first project with Basic availability group so I thought would check before implementing .

As per Microsoft documentation below it says we will need to have Software assurance for failover servers for disaster recovery / high availability.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15

Will greatly appreciate if someone can clarify on this as I will need to have the capabilities to do automatic / manual failover without the need to purchase software assurance

Answer (score 0):

The idea of BAGs is that you can use them on lower cost editions.  You still can't do things like read from it, run backups on it or run DBCC. You can have one secondary node for HA/DR.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15

I'm always of the mindset, though, that licensing questions should only ever be answered by the company (or its partners) that would sue you for non compliance. I'd recommend going with your licensing provider for full clarification as every configuration is different and has different licensing considerations.